# What Windows images are available in Google Cloud?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

Why is it that I cannot create a windows instance using `gcloud`?

```
$ gcloud compute instances create windows-instance --image windows-2008-r2 --metadata gce-initial-windows-user=MYUSERNAME gce-initial-windows-password=MYPASSWORD --zone europe-west1-a
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Failed to find image for alias [windows-2008-r2] in public image project [windows-cloud]. Try specifying a different image using [--image].
- The resource 'projects/windows-cloud' was not found
```

I did try to list any available images but I ended up with no Windows images:

```
$ gcloud compute images list

NAME                                PROJECT        DEPRECATED STATUS
centos-6-v20140718                  centos-cloud              READY
coreos-alpha-423-0-0-v20140828      coreos-cloud              READY
coreos-beta-410-0-0-v20140825       coreos-cloud              READY
coreos-stable-367-1-0-v20140724     coreos-cloud              READY
backports-debian-7-wheezy-v20140814 debian-cloud              READY
debian-7-wheezy-v20140814           debian-cloud              READY
opensuse-13-1-v20140711             opensuse-cloud            READY
rhel-6-v20140718                    rhel-cloud                READY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems there is a [limited availability of Windows instance types](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/operating-systems#windows_server_images):

> Note: Windows Server images are currently in Limited Preview, and require access to use. To sign up to use these images, fill out the [sign up form](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/1_U28LyQztpjlAwR43zNxX2V2bOzAfA3fGEeQ97KrXYM/viewform). Currently, there is limited capacity in the program and there is no guarantee that all requests will be granted access. It may also take some time to process your application and we appreciate your patience.

Comment: Great to hear that you’ve solved your issue! Can you please [accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) so that this question is marked as closed? Thanks!